# Type of an array element when accessed with polymorphic base class (containing virtual functions)

Tags: c++, arrays, object, reference, virtual-functions

`virtual` function resolution happens with pointer/reference and not with object. Now consider below example:

```
struct Base { virtual void foo (); };
struct Derived : Base { void foo (); };

Derived d[2];
Base *p = d;
p[0].foo();  // calls Derived::foo()!
```

My perception was like this: for any array `T arr[SIZE];` the type of `arr[N]` is `T` (and not `T&`), i.e. `arr[N]` is an object. Had it been a case, then in above sample `p[0]` would call `Base::foo()`, because `p[0]` *should* resolved to an object.

However, it's wrong. Can someone explain, why `p[0]` is resolving to `Base&` and *not* `Base` ? Is it because `p[0].foo()` is equivalent to `(p+0)->foo()`?

Comment: This is exactly why virtual functions were invented - so a pointer to a base object can call a derived function. I don't know why you're so surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, it's wrong. Can someone explain, why p[0] is resolving to
>   Base& and not Base ? Is it because p[0].foo() is equivalent to
>   (p+0)->foo()?

You got it -- it is the "array indirection operation".

The following are equivolent:

```
a[1];
*(a + 1)
```

It's in the standard:  Literally, the "array indirection operation" means that `*(a + n)` substitutes for `a[n]`, so the result is a reference to an object, not a copy-constructed value of an object.

This was essential to get polymorphism to work, and to ensure derive types were not "copy-constructed" to base types.

Extending further, the following are also equivolent, and result in a reference-to-object:

```
a[1][2][3];
*(*(*(a + 1) + 2) + 3);
```

[EDIT] To be explicit, in your example, yes, these are exactly equivalent:

```
p[0].foo();
(p+0)->foo();    // The "->" is the "*" indirection
(*(p+0)).foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

> My perception was like this: for any array T arr[SIZE]; the type of
>   arr[N] is T (and not T&), i.e. arr[N] is an object. Had it been a
>   case, then in above sample p[0] would call Base::foo(), because p[0]
>   should resolved to an object.

Be aware that the compiler will *assume* that all elements have `sizeof(T)` size. This means that accessing any element except the first will be Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: That's interesting. I never noticed that, now I got that. +1

Comment: In general this point is quite right, but in the example above the derived type doesn't change in size so the code will work.  Also it is not so unusual to extend a class by just changing the methods and not adding data.  Still, it is probably undefined behaviour in some more more subtle sense.

Comment: @Adrian: The "I added a field and now my code is broken" kind of sense. That's not code that actually works.

Comment: Oh it works all right.  Lots of broken things work.  For a while.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because `p[0].foo()` equivalent to `(p+0)->foo()` ?

If you look into the standard, that's the very definition of the subscript operator.

> The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`

and the result of the dereferentiation is "an lvalue referring to the object". You lose the dynamic type information only when slicing happens (i.e. when the copy constructor of the base type is run to create a copy of your original object), and here it definitely doesn't.

As for the "actual generated code" is concerned, I don't see where's the problem... `p[0].foo()` means `p->foo()`; the compiler will happily generate the code to call the method through the vptr, which has been initialized correctly before the `Derived` constructor to point to the `Derived` vtable. This all will result in `Derived::foo()` being called.

Answer (score 1):

It has to resolve to a reference because array elements can be modified using subscript notation.

Resolving to an object would imply that the result was a copy, and that changing it was either impossible, or would leave the original array unchanged.